# create table with select union has no constraints

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, create-table

I created a table using `select` with a `union`, as follows:

```
create table tableC as
select column1, column2 from tableA
union all
select column1, column2 from tableB
```

The resulting table (`tableC`) has inherited none of the constraints from `tableA` or `tableB`. Why weren't the constraints copied to the new table?

Comment: To answer your unasked question: you could instead `create table tableC as select column1, column2 from tableA` which will duplicate any NOT NULL constraints, then follow up with an insert from tableB.

Answer (score 2):

Using `select ... as ...` to create a table *never* copies constraints. If you want the new table to inherit constraints from the original tables, you must create the new constraints manually.

---

As @Davek points out, `not null` constraints will get copied from a single table `select ... as ...`. I imagine that's because they are both column attributes and constraints. However, once the column has more than one source, it is reasonable that Oracle would not try to apply that constraint.

---

In response to the follow-up question "would it be possible to give `tableC` the same constraints either from `tableA` or `tableB`, after a CTAs?":

Of course it's possible, but there's no single command to do it. You could write a procedure that used dynamic SQL to copy the constraints. However, unless you're looking to automate this behavior, it'll generally be easier to extract the DDL using an IDE and change the table name.

Comment: I think NOT NULL constraints will be created if just one table is referenced....but that's about it. Anything else will have be created manually/indepenently.

Comment: would it be possible, to give tabelC the same constraints either from tableA or TableB, after a ctas?