# how to copy a table without importing data and constraints in Oracle?

Tags: import, oracle11g, create-table

I want to create a new table called `table2` from another table called `table1` without importing data and constraints. I used this query:

```
create table2 as select * from table1 where 1=2;
```

this code created `table2` without any data, but imports constraints from `table1`. Is there a way not to import constraints from `table1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found in the question [create table with select union has no constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514166/create-table-with-select-union-has-no-constraints).

If the select is a union, Oracle will not add any constraints, so simply use the same select twice, and be sure not to include any records in the second select:

```
create table2 as 
select * from table1 where 1=2
union all
select * from table1 where 1=2;
```